# Inserindo dados PHP MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

Galera boa noite. Neste momento estou tentando inserir dados de um formulário no banco de dados. Porém, não esta sendo inserido de jeito nenhum.

Código formulario:

```
<form action="enviar-ponto.php" method="POST">

<input name="nomePonto" value="<?php echo $resultado['nome']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
<input name="cpfPonto" value="<?php echo $resultado['cpf']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
<input name="horarioPonto" value="<?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?>" readonly="readonly">
<?php } ?>

<button> Bate Ponto</button>
</form>
```

Código envia-ponto.php

```
session_start();

include("conexao/conexao.php");


echo "Olá, ".$_SESSION['login']."<BR>";


$nome = $_POST['nomePonto'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpfPonto'];
$horario = $_POST['horarioPonto'];

if($horario > "11:30:00"){

$reck = "INSERT INTO ponto (nome, cpf, horario1, horario2, horario3, horario4) VALUES ('$nome','$cpf','$horario','$horario','$horario','$horario')";

} 

  if(mysqli_query($conexao, $reck)){

    echo "Ponto registrado com sucesso";
  }else{

    echo "Impossível registrar ponto nesse momento";
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Problema resolvido. Eu utilizei o erro padrão do PHP e ele me retornou que o campo no banco de dados estava muito curto para um resultado longo.

attt